# Read File Data stored in An Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, input, output

I have this piece of code that reads data (height, width, row, colum) of a Board (the first item) and blocks (the rest of the items) that are placed on the board:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class readFile {
private Scanner scanner;
public void openFile() {

    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new
File("filePath.txt"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)

    {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
 }
public void readTheFile(){
    while (scanner.hasNext()){

        int height = scanner.nextInt();
        int width = scanner.nextInt();
        int row = scanner.nextInt();
        int col = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s\n", height, width,row,col);
    }
}
public void closeFile(){
    scanner.close();
 }
}
```

This is the output:

```
5 4 0 0  //the dimensions of a board ; height, width, row, column
2 1 0 0 /*the rest are dimensions-heigh,width,row,column of blocks placed on 
2 2 0 1   the board*/
2 1 0 3 
2 1 2 0  
1 2 2 1 
1 1 3 1 
1 1 3 2 
1 1 4 0 
1 1 4 3
```

I want this to be stored in an Arraylist and returned.Please help

[This is what i want to end up with finally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKrND.png)

Comment: Create a POJO which represents each row of data, instead of printing the result, create a new instance of this "row object" and add it to the `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) which represents a individual row of data...

```
public class Row {

    private int height, width, row, col;

    public Row(int height, int width, int row, int col) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

}
```

Modify your `readTheFile` method to populate a `List` with instances of `Row` objects representing each line of the file and return this `List`

```
public List<Row> readTheFile() {
    List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>(25);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {

        int height = scanner.nextInt();
        int width = scanner.nextInt();
        int row = scanner.nextInt();
        int col = scanner.nextInt();

        rows.add(new Row(height, width, row, col));
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Have a look at [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

Comment: Thanks so very much @MadProgrammer ; How do i proceed to print out to the console the output. I want this board and blocks to be printed out on the board graphically. Sorry if i sound too naive, im just a beginner in programming

Comment: Use a `for-loop` to iterate through the `List`, which will give you access to each `Row` (or block). You might need to sort them in some meaningful way depending on what you want to do. Have a look at [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for starters